# Flush interval in elasticsearch bulk processor

Tags: elasticsearch, flush, bulk

I have an index with refresh_interval = 10s, so every 10s all buffered content is saved on disk in a newly created segment. All operations on this index go through a bulk processor.

For synchronization matters between indexes and searches, what we need is to execute the bulk every 5s but without flushing the content, so we want to wait for the index refresh to make these documents visible for search.

Can we achieve this by setting bulk.setFlushInterval(5000)? Or will this provoke 2 flushes, one every 5s due to the bulk and one every 10s due to the index?

Thanks.